# SQLite INSERT command Syntax Help

Tags: syntax, insert, sqlite

Greetings All,

I have a SQLite database that I'm trying to add a new column to an existing table.  My current structure is:

ID_NO, integer
GUIDE, integer
MATERIAL, text

I would like to add a new column which is the first letter of MATERIAL
KEY, text

Here is what I tried, but I get an error that MATERIAL doesn't exist

```
INSERT INTO ERG_DATA (KEY) VALUES ( SUBSTR(MATERIAL,1,1))
```

Is INSERT the right command?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top of my head, you want something like this (two commands)

```
ALTER TABLE erg_data ADD COLUMN key CHAR(1);
UPDATE erg_data SET key = SUBSTR(material, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with SQLite, but in general an Insert statement is used to write data into the table, not change the table definition.

If you want to change the definition of the table, you should look for an Alter statement instead, like Alter Table [tablename] Add Column [columnname] [datatype]